# CountDown Timer - How to Show Year, Months, Weeks as well

Tags: android, countdown

In my program i have to show CountDown Timer and for that i wrote some code, which allow me to get Days, Hours, Minutes and Seconds, but not getting any idea how to calculate Year, Months and weeks as well.

Still i am getting this:

```
days:384 hours:6 minutes:27 seconds:25
```

but i need this:

```
year:1 months:2 weeks:5 days:125 hours:6 minutes:27 seconds:25
```

Check my below code :

```
      public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    String time1="31-08-2015 12:01:00";
    TextView tv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);

        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();  
                String time = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss"; // 12:00

                String dateStart =(String) DateFormat.format(time, start);                          
                String dateStop = time1;


                 SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");  
                // Custom date format
                java.util.Date d1=null;
                java.util.Date d2=null;
                  try {
                        d1 = format.parse(dateStart);
                        d2 = format.parse(dateStop);
                    } catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();             

                long diffdays    =(diff/ (1000*60*60*24));
                long diffHours = ((diff - (1000*60*60*24*diffdays)) / (1000*60*60));                             
                long diffMinutes = (diff - (1000*60*60*24*diffdays) - (1000*60*60*diffHours)) / (1000*60);  
                long diffSeconds =(diff - (1000*60*60*24*diffdays) - (1000*60*60*diffHours) -(1000*60*diffMinutes))/ (1000);                

                String out= "days:"+diffdays+  "hours:"+diffHours+  "Minutes:"+diffMinutes+  "seconds:"+diffSeconds;
                tv.setText(out);

                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        }, 1000); 
    }

}
```

Comment: are you still looking for answer?

Comment: yes because no one has provided correct solution @Rod_Algonquin

Comment: may i know what are you trying to achive?

Comment: will days be only less than the month?? why `days:125`??

Answer (score 1):

I have this code that works for me and is more simple:

```
public static String    dhmsDifference(Date d1, Date d2)
{
    long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
    long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;
    long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
    long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
    long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

    String difference=Long.toString(diffDays)+":"+String.format("%02d", diffHours)+":"+String.format("%02d", diffMinutes)+":"+String.format("%02d", diffSeconds);

    return difference;
}
```

It returns a String, but you can easily adapt it to your code I think.

For month and years, I'd use a Calendar (added it to my code):

```
Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
cal1.setTime(d1);
cal2.setTime(d2);

    long months = cal2.get(Calendar.MONTH)-cal1.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    long years = cal2.get(Calendar.YEAR)-cal1.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    long weeks = cal2.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)-cal1.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
```

You'll need to add some magic for when the year changes, but that's the idea.

EDIT: Makes some tests with this more complete code please:

```
public static String    ymwdhmsDifference(Date d1, Date d2)
{
    long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
    long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;
    long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
    long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
    long totalDiffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    long diffDays = totalDiffDays % 7;

    long diffWeeks = totalDiffDays/7;   // Full weeks are simply days / 7.
    diffDays = diffDays % 7;        // now we get the remaining days.

    Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal1.setTime(d1);
    cal2.setTime(d2);


    long totalDiffYears = cal2.get(Calendar.YEAR)-cal1.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    long totalDiffMonths = Math.max(totalDiffYears*12+cal2.get(Calendar.MONTH)-cal1.get(Calendar.MONTH)-1,0);
    long diffYears = totalDiffMonths / 12;
    // remaining full months
    long diffMonths = totalDiffMonths % 12;

    // now we have to count how many weeks those full months represent, to substract them from the number of weeks...
    Calendar cal3 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal3.setTime(d1);
    int month = cal1.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1, year = cal1.get(Calendar.YEAR), monthDays=0;
    for (int m=0;m<totalDiffMonths;m++) {
        cal3.set(Calendar.MONTH, month++);
        monthDays+=cal3.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        if (month>=12) {
            month = 0;
            year++;
            cal3.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        }
    }
    diffWeeks-=monthDays/7;

    // Note that the number of weeks can be greater than 4 because they are part of non full months.

    String difference="Y: "+Long.toString(diffYears)+" M: "+Long.toString(diffMonths)+" W: "+Long.toString(diffWeeks)+" D: "+Long.toString(diffDays)+" H: "+String.format("%02d", diffHours)+" M: "+String.format("%02d", diffMinutes)+" S: "+String.format("%02d", diffSeconds);

    return difference;
}
```

Comment: i have to calculate year, months, weeks as well

Comment: and i already ticked your answer as useful, and once you done with this.. i will accept your solution as well

Comment: This should work: I added some code that you can test which doesn't use a library. Be aware that months are considered "full" when the entire month is in the range.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can simple use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library to do it

```
Interval interval = new Interval(startDate.getTime(), endDate.getTime());
Period period = interval.toPeriod();
String strDiff = "Year: " + period.getYears() + "/ Month: " + period.getMonths() + "/ Days: " + period.getDays() + "/ Hours: " + period.getHours() + "/ Minutes: " + period.getMinutes() + "/ Seconds: " + period.getSeconds();
```

Comment: I think both solutions are incomplete because you will not get the number of full months with that, will you?

Comment: What is supposed result if I check day difference between today and a year before?
1 yeaer 0 month 0 week 0 day?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_count_down);
        final TextView time = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtCountDown);

        final GregorianCalendar currentTime=new  GregorianCalendar (2014,9,1,9,16,0);
        GregorianCalendar targetTime=new  GregorianCalendar (2016,5,1,11,2,0);
        long difference =  targetTime.getTimeInMillis() - currentTime.getTimeInMillis();
        new CountDownTimer(difference,1000) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long arg0) {
                Calendar countdownDuration = Calendar.getInstance();
                countdownDuration.setTimeInMillis(currentTime.getTimeInMillis() + arg0);
                int year = countdownDuration.get(Calendar.YEAR)-currentTime.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int month = countdownDuration.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int day = countdownDuration.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)-1;
                int hour = countdownDuration.get(Calendar.HOUR);
                int minute = countdownDuration.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                int sec = countdownDuration.get(Calendar.SECOND);

                time.setText("Years: " + year + "\nMonth:" + month + "\nDays:" + day +"\nHour:" + hour 
                        + "\nMinute" + minute + "\nSecond:" + sec);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        }.start();
    }
```

Screenshot
http://postimg.org/image/4h3pychgd/

Comment: I am testing your code above for a needed Calendar difference.  Why is -1 subtracted from the "Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH"?

Comment: Code looks good but math doesn't seem to work.  Your output screenshot says 2 years and 5 months for the difference but the result should be more like 1 year and 8 months.  That is, add 1 year and 8 months to September 2014 and you get May 2016 for the end date.  Adding your 2 years and 5 months output to the beginning date of September 2014 would result in February 2017 for the end date not May 2016.  Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

```
  private static long converTimeStringINToMillis(String time) {

            long milliseconds = 0;

            try {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));

                // 25/06/2014 8:41:26

                Date date;

                date = sdf.parse(time);
                milliseconds = date.getTime();
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                milliseconds = 0;
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return milliseconds;
        }

        public static String  setLastSeenTime(String time){


            long milliseconds = Math.abs(System.currentTimeMillis() - converTimeStringINToMillis(time));

            String lastSeen = "";

            int seconds = (int)milliseconds/1000;
            if(seconds < 60) 
                lastSeen = String.valueOf(seconds) + "sec ago";
            else if(seconds >60 && seconds < 3600)
                lastSeen = String.valueOf((int)seconds/60) + " min ago";
            else if(seconds > 3600 && seconds < 86400)
                lastSeen = String.valueOf((int)seconds/3600) + " hours ago";
            else if(seconds > 86400 && seconds < 172800)
                lastSeen =" Yesterday";
            else if(seconds > 172800 && seconds < 2592000)
                lastSeen = String.valueOf((int)(seconds/(24*3600))) + " days ago";
            else if(seconds > 2592000)
                lastSeen = String.valueOf((int)(seconds/(30*24*3600))) + " months ago";


            return lastSeen;


        }
```

add accroding ur Code ..